How to reduce .exe size that uses pytorch with cuda?
I'm working on a project using PyTorch with CUDA, and everything runs smoothly in my development environment. However, when I package the project into an .exe file with PyInstaller, the file size ends up at 4.5GB, with PyTorch alone accounting for around 4GB of that size. Does anyone know of efficient ways to manage PyTorch dependencies when creating an .exe file to reduce the final size? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
from torchvision.models import mobilenet_v2,MobileNet_V2_Weights
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from torch.nn import Sequential
from torch.cuda import is_available
from torch import no_grad,load

these are the imports that took 4GB Memory Alone.
